# "he will come by/at 11 a.m."

Tags: prepositions, time, time-words

Which of the following is correct?

> 1.​ He will come **by** 11 a.m.
>   2.​ He will come **at** 11 a.m.

Or if both are correct, is there any difference in meaning between the two?

Comment: Either, both, or neither could be correct. We'd need context to tell which one is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

> He will come **by** 11 a.m

He will come **before** 11 a.m. He might come **at** 10 a.m. or even at 9 a.m., this will be still considered "by 11 a.m." The main thing is that when the clock strikes 11 a.m. he will already be there.

> He will come **at** 11 a.m.

He will come when it will be 11 a.m. on the clock. He might come 4 minutes later or 5 minutes earlier, but he will come roughly **at** 11 a.m.

---

The difference is that in the second sentence we allow that he might come slightly later than 11 a.m.

In the first sentence, it is not that important when exactly he arrives, it is more important that he arrives **before** the mentioned moment in time.

> We can begin our meeting. John is absent, but he will come **by** 11 a.m. so there will be plenty of time for him to make his speech.

Answer (score 2):

Both the sentences are correct grammatically, with some difference in meaning.

The sentence #1 with the preposition 'at' is indicative of the exact time (11 a.m.) when he will come.

The sentence #2 with the preposition 'by' implies  that he he will come before or not later than 11 a.m.